# Updated to wdio8. Running the automation is giving error webdriver: Couldn't download Chromedriver v116.0.5845.96 on mac. Working fine on windows

Tags: selenium-webdriver, ui-automation, webdriver-io, wdio

WebdriverIO Version
latest

Node.js Version
16

Capabilities in wdio.conf:

```
capabilities: [{
    // capabilities for local browser web tests
    browserName: browser, // or "firefox", "microsoftedge", "safari"
    browserVersion: 'stable'
}],
```

Earlier I was using selenium-standalone-service for browser driver management. The jobs started failing when chrome updated to v116 due to chromedriver version mismatch. I came across chrome for testing solution on internet and updated webdriverIO to the latest version to take advantage of it. Post that the job is working fine on windows but when I run it on mac it fails with the below error.

```
2023-09-07T10:10:50.233Z DEBUG @wdio/cli:utils: Finished to run "onPrepare" hook in 2ms
2023-09-07T10:10:50.233Z INFO @wdio/utils: Setting up browser driver for: chrome@stable
2023-09-07T10:10:50.234Z INFO @wdio/utils: Setting up browser binaries for: chrome@stable
2023-09-07T10:10:50.310Z INFO webdriver: Downloading Chromedriver v116.0.5845.96
2023-09-07T10:10:50.311Z INFO @wdio/local-runner: Shutting down spawned worker
2023-09-07T10:10:50.312Z WARN webdriver: Couldn't download Chromedriver v116.0.5845.96: ENOENT: no such file or directory, mkdir '/apps', trying to find known good version...
2023-09-07T10:10:50.563Z INFO @wdio/local-runner: Waiting for 0 to shut down gracefully
2023-09-07T10:10:50.563Z INFO @wdio/local-runner: shutting down
Error: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, mkdir '/apps'
[Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, mkdir '/apps'] {
  errno: -2,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'mkdir',
  path: '/apps'
}
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
```

This is happening only when I run it on slave machine via jenkins. If I run the code on my local machine it runs just fine.

Anyone has any clue about what's going wrong here? I am not able to figure out what is /apps directory. I am not using is anywhere in my code

Comment: @Nils Try and run in sudo mode. It resolved the issue for me

Answer (score 0):

The issue was due to some permissions. I ran using sudo and it worked.